# How can I use Rails' HTTP caching helpers with an `updated_on` timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-caching

I'm working on a new Rails 6 API app (to serve both a React.js front end and other services) that, for historical reasons, shares a backend MySQL database with two other applications that have existed since the early days of Rails.

We want the new API to be as performant as possible, so I had been hoping to use Rails' HTTP caching (`stale?`, `fresh_when`, etc.) to ensure that repeated requests for the same endpoint can take advantage of browser-level caching. In particular, I have a collection query for a dashboard page which I dearly want to be cacheable.

Unfortunately, this old school database uses `created_on` and `updated_on` as its timestamp column names, and both `fresh_when` and the ETag generators it calls expect the update timestamp to be called `updated_at`.

Our other existing apps use the values in the timestamps all over the place, so I'd prefer not to have to force through changes totalling hundreds of lines of code on them.

I can manually calculate in a `last_modified` value into both `stale?` and `fresh_when`, but the etag generation has a dependency on `ActiveRecord::Relation#cache_key_with_version` which, in turn, calls `ActiveRecord::Relation#cache_version` with its default timestamp attribute name of `:updated_at`.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to proceed? I'm not averse to hand rolling my own caching code in the controller, but if there was a way to leverage as much Rails code as possible that'd be brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I can think of is using `alias_attribute`:  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute

You can use `alias_attribute :updated_at, :updated_on` in the models you wish. This way you don't need to change the db column, or override the `cache_version` method.

Comment: That's a plausible suggestion! I shall try it out and report back…